# How to find out which JSRs are used in a jar file?

Tags: java, mobile, jar, jsr

I want to know if a jar file can run properly on my phone, I know JSRs that my phone supports，but I don't know which JSRs are used in a jar，so can anyone suggest me any tool?

Comment: Can you be specific about which JSRs you are talking about.  According to the JCP site, there have been ~350 JSRs covering a vast range of topics.

Comment: If your phone is supporting certain JSRs chances are it already has JAR file or files it needs to support those JSRs on it.

Answer (score 0):

May be this [discussion](http://www.java.net/node/669514) will helps you. And also look at this discussion, [Programmatically checking JSR with j2me](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?99153-Programmatically-checking-JSR-support-in-j2me-app)